# On install, automatically create page and set it as front page

Tags: installation, automation

On install, I want a page automatically created and being set as front page. I able to create the page but unable to set it as front page.

Below is `WP Install Defaults` codes which automatically create page after install:

```
function wp_install_defaults( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb, $wp_rewrite, $table_prefix;

    $now = current_time( 'mysql' );
    $now_gmt = current_time( 'mysql', 1 );

    // First Page
    $first_page = sprintf( __( "This is an example page.
        Have fun!" ), admin_url() );
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->posts, array(
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_date' => $now,
        'post_date_gmt' => $now_gmt,
        'post_content' => $first_page,
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'post_title' => __( 'Sample Page' ),
        'post_name' => __( 'sample-page' ),
        'post_modified' => $now,
        'post_modified_gmt' => $now_gmt,
        'post_type' => 'page',
    ));
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->postmeta, array( 'post_id' => 2, 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'meta_value' => 'default' ) );
}
```

I stuck here, which I have no idea how to set the page as front page.

Below is code taken from Twenty Seventeen theme which I have no clue how to port to `WP Install Defaults`

```
add_theme_support( 'starter-content', array(
        // ...
        'options' => array(
            'show_on_front' => 'page',
            'page_on_front' => '{{sample-page}}',
        ),
    // ...
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use [**`register_activation_hook`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook), this hook runs when a wordpress plugin is installed.

I would also replace the call to the **`$wpdb`** for inserting post with [**`wp_insert_post`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/).

[**`wp_insert_post`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) returns the post ID on success and this can be used to update the option for both **`page_on_front`** and **`show_on_front`**.

```
function wp_install_defaults( $user_id ) {

    $now = current_time( 'mysql' );
    $now_gmt = current_time( 'mysql', 1 );

    // First Page
    $first_page = sprintf( __( "This is an example page.
        Have fun!" ), admin_url() );
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'pagename' => 'sample-page'
    ) );
    if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
        // Add the page using the data from the array above
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'post_author' => $user_id,
                'post_date' => $now,
                'post_date_gmt' => $now_gmt,
                'post_content' => $first_page,
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'post_title' => __( 'Sample Page' ),
                'post_name' => __( 'sample-page' ),
                'post_modified' => $now,
                'post_modified_gmt' => $now_gmt,
                'post_type' => 'page',
            )
        );

        if ( $post_id )
        {
            update_option( 'page_on_front', $post_id );
            update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
        }
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wp_install_defaults' );
```